# using jquery layout within twitter bootstrap dialog

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jquery-layout, bootstrap-dialog

I need to use the jquery layout in a bootstrap dialog .I have tried using the jquery layout in a simple example and it works : [Simple_Example](http://jsfiddle.net/5EECD/393/) but when I use it in a dialog it does not seem to work.

**The jsfiddle for it : [Dialog with layout](http://jsfiddle.net/cp67J/1049/).**

My HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-default" id="openBtn">Open modal</a>
<div class="modal fade hide" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" >
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h3>Modal header</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <div id="content">
<div class="ui-layout-center">Center</div>
<div class="ui-layout-west">West</div>
</div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('#openBtn').click(function(){
 $('#content').layout({ applyDefaultStyles: true });
    $('#myModal').modal({show:true})
});
```

CSS:

```
#content{

    height:200px;
}
```

Comment: The TidyUp button is your friend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With modals, tabs, etc., you need to wait until the element is sized and in the DOM before modifying or applying functionality to them. In this case, we'll use Bootstrap's `shown` callback.

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/cp67J/1053

```
$('#openBtn').click(function () {
    $('#myModal').modal({
        show: true
    }).on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
        $('#content').layout({
            applyDefaultStyles: true
        });
    });
});
```

---

Here's how you might prevent the visible style change:

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/6Y5DC

```
#content {
    opacity: 0;
}

$('#openBtn').click(function () {
    $('#myModal').modal({
        show: true
    }).on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
        $('#content').layout({
            applyDefaultStyles: true
        });
        $('#content').animate({
            opacity: 1
        }, 400);
    });
});
```

Comment: @isherwood-Thanks for your valuable inputs and solution.Is there any fix to populate the dialog instantly with layout.Now there is a visible delay  after the opening of the dialog.Hope you can give some insight regarding on this.

Comment: Sure--hide your content, then fade it in after you apply the styles.

Comment: i didn't quite get you

Comment: See above for a solution.